# NASM: How to resolve these unresolved externals?

Tags: linker, nasm

I'm trying to get started learning basic assembly with Paul A. Carter's book "PC Assembly Language." However I'm unable to run the first example Carter provides, so I'm kind of stuck until I figure this out.

I assembled the example "first.asm" without any problem, but I can't figure out how to link these files: first.obj, driver.c, asm_io.obj into an executable. In the comment section of first.asm Carter gives these instructions for creating an executable (I'm using Windows 10, VS community 2015 developer command prompt):

```
    ; Using MS C/C++
    ; nasm -f win32 first.asm
    ; cl first.obj driver.c asm_io.obj
```

I'm doing exactly that but I'm getting a fatal error 2 unresolved externals, _printf and _scanf. I have every necessary file that I can think of in the same directory, and I'm compiling in that directory.
Driver.c calls the function defined in and it uses a header file called "CDECL.h"; I have this file in my directory, but I don't understand much about this header file. I wonder if the problem is here. I haven't altered it or anything. I assembled asm_io.asm according to Dr. Carter's instructions.

Not too far into asm_io.asm is see this:

```
    extern  _scanf, _printf, _getchar, _putchar, _fputs
```

So here are the unresolved externals. Shouldn't they be defined in stdio.h? Driver.c includes stdio.h, shouldn't the linker be able to resolve these symbols be looking at stdio.h? What might I be missing?

ps. I'm new to programming in general, and this is my first stack overflow question. I'm open to any and all criticism/feedback. I'll provide more information if you need it, I just didn't want to post a massive wall of text and code if not necessary.

Comment: *cl* is a linker, can't eat *c* files. Also those function are defined by the *CRT*, include whatever lib they are implemented in.

Comment: @MargaretBloom `cl` *is* the [MS commandline C/C++ compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx)
`link` is the [MS commandline linker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx5b050y.aspx).

Comment: @MikeKinghan Whoops, My bad. I confused the twos.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You need to understand:-

The difference between a *header file*, e.g.

```
foo.h // C or maybe C++ header file)
```

and a *library*, e.g.

```
foo.lib  foo.dll // Windows
libfoo.a, libfoo.so // Unix/Linux
```

that implements the calling interface that is (merely) described in a header file.

The difference between *compiling or assembling* a source file, e.g.

```
bar.c // C source file
bar.asm // Assembly source, Windows
bar.s // Assembly source, Unix/Linux
```

to make an object file. e.g.

```
bar.obj // Windows
bar.o // Unix/Linux
```

and *linking* object files and libraries together make a complete executable.

Linking can succeed only if the linker is supplied with (or knows by default)
the names and locations of object files and/or libraries that provide 
implementations of all the functions that are called in the program - including
functions whose calling interfaces are described in header files. Otherwise
unresolved symbol errors ensue.

Research these points and you'll quickly get yourself unstuck. See [this
pretty good introductory tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html), which although it is about getting
started with the [GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/) rather
than with assembly language programming, will clarify the principles
and distinctions you need to grasp.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! Currently researching away :)